# Csv DataGridView Conversion to XML Winforms

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq, datagridview

so I am working on my project and I want to write datagridview which is from a CSV file into XML file and I have achieved that but what I want to know if there is any way to sort the order view or change the outcome of XML what I want is to sort Alphabetical order from a specific column.  this is my code for the saving XML file.

```
    if (saveFileDialogXml.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Xml Alphabetical order code goes here

            DataTable dst = new DataTable();
            dst = (DataTable)Datagridview1.DataSource;
            dst.TableName = "Data";
            dst.WriteXml(saveFileDialogXml.FileName);

        }

        }
```

**but the output of this is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
```

```
<Item_x0020_Code>Item Code</Item_x0020_Code>
<Item_x0020_Description>Item Description</Item_x0020_Description>
<Current_x0020_Count>Current Count</Current_x0020_Count>
<On_x0020_Order>On Order</On_x0020_Order>
```

as you can see it even put the Hexadecimal and it just throws everything there, so I was wondering if i can reformat it the way I want it to display like removing the  *x0020*. So I tried using LINQ to see if there was a problem with file, but I keep getting another error which says

> System.Xml.XmlException: 'The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.'

This is the LINQ code :

```
var xmlFile = new XElement("root",
                from line in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\StockFile\stocklist.csv")
                .Where(n => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n))
                where !line.StartsWith(",") && line.Length > 0
                let parts = line.Split(',')
                select new XElement("Item Code",
                                    new XElement("Test1", parts[0]),
                                    new XElement("Test2", parts[1])

                                    )

             );
```

Also, I am new to C# and my first post here so please excuse the messy writing or placements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late Reply I kinda figured it out so forgot to close or mark an answer anyway if any of you run to the same thing all I did was this

```
    // Save file dialogue XML file.
        if (saveFileDialogXml.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

           //try block to catch exception and handle it.
            try
            {
               //Changing Data Table name to stock.
                string Stock = ((DataTable)Datagridview1.DataSource).TableName;
            }

            //Catching the exception and handling it.
            catch (Exception)
            {
                string es = "Please Open The File Before Saving it";
                string title = "Error";
                MessageBox.Show(es, title);


            }

// instatiate new DataTable.
            DataTable dt = new DataTable
            {
                TableName = "Stock"
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < Datagridview1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                //if (dataGridView1.Columns[i].Visible) // Add's only Visible columns.
                //{
                string headerText = Datagridview1.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                headerText = Regex.Replace(headerText, "[-/, ]", "_");

                DataColumn column = new DataColumn(headerText);
                dt.Columns.Add(column);
                //}
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow DataGVRow in Datagridview1.Rows)
            {
                DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
                // Add's only the columns that I need
                dataRow[0] = DataGVRow.Cells["Item Code"].Value;
                dataRow[1] = DataGVRow.Cells["Item Description"].Value;
                dataRow[2] = DataGVRow.Cells["Current Count"].Value;
                dataRow[3] = DataGVRow.Cells["On Order"].Value;

                dt.Rows.Add(dataRow); //dt.Columns.Add();
            }
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

           //Finally the save part:
            XmlTextWriter xmlSave = new XmlTextWriter(saveFileDialogXml.FileName, Encoding.UTF8)
            {
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            };
            ds.DataSetName = "Data";
            ds.WriteXml(xmlSave);
            xmlSave.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            DataTable dst = new DataTable();
            int startColumn = 5;
            for(int i = dst.Columns.Count - 1; i >= startColumn; i--)
            {
                dst = dst.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => dst.Columns[i]).CopyToDataTable();
            }
```

Comment: I tried that code you suggested me but the data is still the same and same output nothing has changed. I still get _x0020_

Comment: It is due to spaces.  You have "On Order" as the column header name.  The first row of the csv is being used as the column names and the element names.  So the WriteXml method is adding 0x0020 (the ascii code for a space).  Xml doesn't allow spaces in the element name.  What most people do is to replace the space in the column name with a "_".